# Extract document name from print job

Tags: printing, postscript

Is there a reliable way to extract a document name or job name from a postscript print job if you have the raw postscript data?

I've seen print release station software that labels each job with a document name or url it was printed from, so it seems possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *reliable* way to do this, as there is no such (metadata) information in the PostScript language. **If** your files are DSC (Document Structuring Convention) compliant then you can look for comments. These are documented in the DSC reference manual. Valid PostScript files need not be DSC compliant.

Other than that, there is no information there to extract, at least as far as PostScript is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

To extract document name from print job using C++.

```
    #include <WinSpool.h>

wstring GetDocumentName(wstring m_strFriendlyName)
{
  wstring strDocName = L"";
  HANDLE hPrinter ;
  if ( OpenPrinter(const_cast<LPWSTR>(m_strFriendlyName.c_str()), &hPrinter, NULL) == 0 )
  {    
    /*OpenPrinter call failed*/
    return false;
  }

  DWORD dwBufsize = 0;
  PRINTER_INFO_2* pinfo = 0;
  GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2,(LPBYTE)pinfo, dwBufsize, &dwBufsize); //Get dwBufsize

  PRINTER_INFO_2* pinfo2 = (PRINTER_INFO_2*)malloc(dwBufsize); //Allocate with dwBufsize
  GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2,(LPBYTE)pinfo2, dwBufsize, &dwBufsize);

  DWORD numJobs = pinfo2->cJobs;
  free(pinfo2); 

  JOB_INFO_1 *pJobInfo = 0;
  DWORD bytesNeeded = 0, jobsReturned = 0;

  //Get info about jobs in queue.
  EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, numJobs, 1, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo, 0,&bytesNeeded,&jobsReturned);
  pJobInfo = (JOB_INFO_1*) malloc(bytesNeeded);
  EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, numJobs, 1, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo, bytesNeeded, &bytesNeeded, &jobsReturned);


  JOB_INFO_1 *pJobInfoInitial = pJobInfo;
  for(unsigned short count = 0; count < jobsReturned; count++)
  {
    if (pJobInfo != NULL)
    {
      strDocName  = pJobInfo->pDocument; // Document name
      DWORD dw = pJobInfo->Status;         
    }
    pJobInfo++;
  }

  free(pJobInfoInitial);
  ClosePrinter( hPrinter );
  return strDocName;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need some kind of header-file inclusion? And a function definition? This answer feels incomplete.

Comment: sorry for that.. i added header file and function definition.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be seeing is the document name that the application submitted to the print spooler.  Also, it may not be reliable but most print drivers put the document name in PJL or XML at the top of the print job.  With some flexible rules you might be able to pull this data with some confidence.

This, of course, assumes that the PS data was generated by a printer drivers.